# Allow only positive and negative numbers in textbox using JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have a textbox called count. I want to enter only positive and negative numbers in the textbox using JavaScript or jQuery regular expression. Do not allow "text" and "decimals" and "special characters" in the textbox. Even copy and paste also it should take only positive or negative numbers.

**Important:**

1. If I copy and paste text or decimal or special character also it should not take. It should take only positive or negative numbers.
2. I want to enter and paste negative values without decimal.
3. Arrow keys should work.
4. <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> like this buttons also should work.

Please check the following fiddle and please modify this.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44pc78pj/175/)

```js
 $(".allownumericwithoutdecimal").on("keypress keyup blur",function (event) {    
           $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d].+/, ""));
            if ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

```html
   
 <span>Int</span>
<input type="text" name="numeric" class='allownumericwithoutdecimal'>
<div>Numeric values only allowed  (Without Decimal Point) </div>
```

I am new for regex. Please help me for do this.

Comment: Is `+` sign allowed for positive numbers ?

Comment: not required. "-" symbol only required.

Comment: and "-" symbol should come only one time at the beginning. Not more than one.

Comment: Code doesnt work as expected

Answer (score 1):

The regex you are looking for is this:

**Regex:** `^-?[0-9]+$`

**Explanation:**

- It checks for optional `-`ve sign. And only allows digits.
- I have used `[0-9]` instead of `\d` because later one means numbers in different languages.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rC6tS6/2)

***PS: Am not a Javascript programmer so if anyone want to add fiddle or use this regex, go ahead.***

Comment: Sorry noob. Please see my points what I have mentioned. Even copy paste also it should not take. And should allow arrow keys. Can you please add this example in jsfiddle?

Comment: @sathishkumar: Well yea this is not the complete solution. It's only the regex part. Good luck with the fiddle as am not a Javascript programmer.

Comment: This regex is good to use on the `blur` event, as a final validation. Actually, a regex is basic here, the problem is the code. See [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ny1ey9xc/) adapted a bit from my former post. No idea if it works the way you need.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks. I think your fiddle is what OP requires. You should post it as answer.

Comment: @noob: No, I do not think it is working well. I cannot paste `12345` into the field.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew:  yes copy and paste is not working. If it will work means, this is my functionality. How can I copy and paste here. Other things are working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This is also achievable without regex using Javascript keypress and charCode.

```
<input type="number" (keypress)="keypress($event, $event.target.value)" >

keypress(evt, value){

    if (evt.charCode >= 48 && evt.charCode <= 57 || (value=="" && evt.charCode == 45))       
    {  
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The given code won't allow user to enter alphabets nor decimal on runtime, just positive and negative integer values.